# MongoServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT getting this error when trying to connect to mongoDB VM on GCP from local

Tags: php, mongodb, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, mongo-shell

I have successfully created a mongoDB VM on GAP, and its ssh connection is possible,

- internal ip of mongoDB's VM is : 1.2.3.4
- external ip is : 5.6.7.8

(mentioned ip's are just example)
i've also created /etc/mongodb.conf file on mongo VM , which looks like this

```
security:
   
 authorization: "enabled"

....

#network interfaces

net:

  port : 27017

  bindIP: 127.0.0.1,1.2.3.4,5.6.7.8
```

after that i created the admin database and one user in it

After this configuration, now  i want to connect to the mongo from my local,
so i have installed mongosh in my local machine and trying to connect to the mongoDB using the connecting string

```
mongosh "mongodb://admin:admin_password@5.6.7.8:27017/?authSource=admin"
 but im getting below error
Current Mongosh Log ID: 61ef7f863272be2ef074d2ad
Connecting to:          mongodb://<credentials>@5.6.7.8:27017/?authSource=admin&directConnection=true
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

what i've missed in conf or what extra needs to be done?

referring [this link](https://bluemedora.com/mongodb-on-google-cloud-how-to-set-it-up-and-keep-it-healthy/)

Comment: Are you able to telnet port 27017 with external ip from your local machine? If not, you can try accessing mongo host via [SSH Tunnel](https://serverfault.com/a/597893/334168) from your local machine.

Comment: Do i need to  add the mongodb extension in php.ini file in GAP, if yes, how can i add it

Comment: When we need to connect MongoDB via php then we will need to add this extension

Comment: i have added the extension and the error "NO class found for mongo driver manager" is gone but
i still get this error "Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set"
what should i do now

Comment: i have actually deployed my php application in GAP, and the bind ip address i same as i have mentioned above, but still getting this error when i run the application,
on local also im getting sam error and on php application deployed on google app engine getting the same error

Comment: Like I said, it seems port 27017 is not accessible so you'll need to allow this port for incoming in firewall. Reference https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/administration/use-firewall/

Comment: like you said i have added the firewall, but still same error,
in mongodb.conf file , bindIP should be internal and external IP of instance , correct?

Comment: The bindIP will just be the external ip that you are letting connect to mongo

Comment: so what extra configuration do i have to do to make a succesfull connection